# What is the use of catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime) for ROS Python packages defining new messages or services?

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin-package, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile) ROS Wiki page in **Section 1.1 Messages and Services** states that we need to add the following in CMakeLists.txt for all ROS Python packages defining new messages or services:

`catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime)`

Can someone explain why is this required?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237554/what-is-the-use-of-catkin_package(catkin_depends-message_runtime)-for-ros-python-packages-defining-new-messages-or-services?/) by [khatribharat](https://answers.ros.org/users/26852/khatribharat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It ensures that when another package asks for this packages headers, libraries, etc. by using find_package, that those include the headers and libraries from message runtime as well. This necessary because there are headers provided by message runtime (either directly or indirectly) that are included by the generated code for your messages in this package.

*edit* more specifically for Python I believe there is Python code which provided somehow by message runtime that the generated Python code for your messages will import.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [khatribharat](https://answers.ros.org/users/26852/khatribharat/) on 2016-06-21**:
Can you elaborate the `specifically for Python` part? My question is specifically related to Python packages.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-06-21**:
Messages are not language specific. While you might only use them in Python someone else might use the messages from your package with C++.